# Show posts from TableView only from current user login

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a viewcontroller displaying some post using a tableview and cells. All the datas are being fetched from Firebase ( Database and Users).

I have a login screen before to arrive to the feedview.

I'd like to show only the pots from the current user login in that tableview controller. How is that possible ?

My database is build like this:

[image]

For my Signin Page, I am using the following:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  MobileAppDemo
//
//  Created by Mikko Hilpinen on 27.10.2016.
//  Copyright © 2016 Mikkomario. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import SwiftKeychainWrapper

fileprivate struct RegisterInfo
{
let email: String
let password: String
}

class SignInVC: UIViewController
{
@IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    if User.currentUserId != nil
    {
        print("AUTH: USING EXISTING KEYCHAIN")
        User.startTrackingCurrentUser()
        //performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToFeed", sender: nil)
    }
    else
    {
        print("AUTH: NO EXSTING KEYCHAIN")
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
{
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    print("AUTH: Preparing for segue \(segue.identifier)")

    if let registrationVC = segue.destination as? RegisterVC
    {
        print("AUTH: Found registration VC")

        if let info = sender as? RegisterInfo
        {
            print("AUTH: Sending email (\(info.email)) and password (\(info.password.characters.count) chars) information: ")
            registrationVC.setBaseInfo(email: info.email, password: info.password)
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func signInButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    if let email = emailField.text, let password = passwordField.text
    {
        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password)
        {
            (user, error) in

            if let error = error
            {
                // TODO: Handle other errors here as well
                switch FIRAuthErrorCode(rawValue: error._code)!
                {
                case .errorCodeUserNotFound:
                    print("AUTH: USER NOT FOUND -> CREATING NEW USER")
                    print("AUTH: Sending email \(email) and password \(password.characters.count) characters")
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "RegisterUser", sender: RegisterInfo(email: email, password: password))
                default: print("AUTH: ERROR IN EMAIL LOGIN \(error)") // TODO: Inform user
                }
            }
            else
            {
                print("AUTH: EMAIL AUTH SUCCESSFUL")
                User.currentUserId = user?.uid
                User.startTrackingCurrentUser()
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToFeed", sender: nil)
            }
        }
    }
    // TODO: Inform user that the field contents are missing
}


fileprivate func firebaseAuth(with credential: FIRAuthCredential)
{
    if FIRAuth.auth() == nil
    {
        print("AUTH: NO AUTH SERVICE AVAILABLE")
    }

    FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential)
    {
        (user, error) in

        if let error = error
        {
            print("AUTH: UNABLE TO AUTHENTICATE TO FIREBASE")
            print("AUTH: \(error)")
        }
        else
        {
            if let user = user
            {
                print("AUTH: SUCCESSFULLY AUTHENTICATED WITH FIREBASE")

                // Updates current user data
                var userName = "User"
                var image: UIImage?

                if let retrievedName = user.displayName
                {
                    userName = retrievedName
                }
                if let retrievedImageUrl = user.photoURL
                {
                    if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: retrievedImageUrl)
                    {
                        image = UIImage(data: data)
                    }
                }

                User.post(uid: user.uid, provider: user.providerID, userName: userName, image: image)
                {
                    user in

                    User.currentUser = user
                    User.startTrackingCurrentUser()

                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToFeed", sender: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
 }
```

To display my data in the table view, I'm using this view controller:

```
//
//  Feed.swift
//  MobileAppDemo
//
//  Created by Mikko Hilpinen on 31.10.2016.
//  Copyright © 2016 Mikkomario. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage
import SwiftKeychainWrapper
import SwiftyJSON

var posts = [Post]()
var selectedIndexPath: Int = 0

class FeedVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var feedTableView: UITableView!

private var readPosts: ObserveTask?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    feedTableView.dataSource = self
    feedTableView.delegate = self

    readPosts = Post.observeList(from: Post.parentReference.queryOrdered(byChild: Post.PROPERTY_CREATED)) {
        observedPosts in

        posts = observedPosts.reversed()
        self.feedTableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell  {
    let cell = self.feedTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MessageCell")! as UITableViewCell

    let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
    let titleLabel = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel

    titleLabel.text = posts[indexPath.row].title
    titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0

    Storage.getImage(with: posts[indexPath.row].imageUrl){
        postPic in
        imageView.image = postPic
    }

    return cell

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath.row
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "push", sender: self)
    self.feedTableView.reloadData()
}
}
```

and finally for my Cells:

```
//
//  MessageCell.swift
//  MobileAppDemo
//
//  Created by Mikko Hilpinen on 31.10.2016.
//  Copyright © 2016 Mikkomario. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import FirebaseStorage

class MessageCell: UITableViewCell
{

@IBOutlet weak var messageImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var messageTextView: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var titleTextView: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var linkbutton: UIButton!


private var post: Post!

func configureCell(tableView: UITableView, post: Post)
{
    self.post = post

    // Basic info
   titleTextView.text = post.title
    messageTextView.text = post.caption

    // Post user
    User.get(id: post.creatorId)
    {
        postCreator in 


    }



    // Image
    Storage.getImage(with: post.imageUrl)
    {
        postPic in

        self.messageImageView.image = postPic
        // Row height changes so table needs to be reset
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
}
```

If anybody have any clue / suggestion how I can achieve it ?? It will be incredible :) :)

Thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your `Posts` database reference with `queryOrdered(byChild:)` add `queryEqual(toValue:)` and compare it with `User.currentUserId`.

```
readPosts = Post.observeList(from: Post.parentReference
                                       .queryOrdered(byChild: Post.PROPERTY_CREATED)
                                       .queryEqual(toValue: User.currentUserId)) {

    observedPosts in

    posts = observedPosts.reversed()
    self.feedTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Thanks,

hmm... I have data from the cells information being display like that . .. 

But funny if I use:     
        readPosts = Post.observeList(from: Post.parentReference.queryOrdered(byChild: "creator").queryEqual(toValue: "o9epRntmZaNe2LdTUJV2g1zr54C2"))
        
        {
            observedPosts in
            
            posts = observedPosts.reversed()
            self.feedTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

By putting manually the value of the one user ID it works . . . how to call the value in a dynamic way do you think ?

Comment: @tibewww But you are storing the value in `User.currentUserId` then why is not working, try printing value of `User.currentUserId` and check it has value or not?

Comment: @tibewww Welcome mate :)